# Basic probability: is this conditional density function valid?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that $0\le X\le 1$ and $0\le Y\le 1$. The joint p.d.f is $$f_{X,Y} (x, y) = \begin{cases} 4xy,& \text{if $0\le X\le 1$, $0\le Y\le 1$}\\0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ This is a valid p.d.f. The conditional probability density function is $$f_{X|Y} (x|y) = \begin{cases} \frac{4xy}{2y},& \text{if $0\le X\le 1$, $0\le Y\le 1$}\\0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ Is the conditional p.d.f valid? If not, how do I calculate $P(X\gt 0|Y=0)$?

Comment: No - it does not integrate to $1$ over $x$.  Where did you get the $2y$ term from? Might symmetry and separability suggest something for the conditional pdf?  In any case, I would have thought $P(X\gt 0\mid Y=0)$ is clearly $1$

Comment: I got it from $f_{Y}(y)$? I know $P(X\gt 0|Y=0)$ is clearly 1 too. But I want to see how the probability calculus assigns it that value, instead of basing it on commonsense.

Comment: My mistake: $\frac{4xy}{2y} = 2x  \text{ if } 0\le X\le 1$ is correct and does integrate to $1$ over $x$.  As a check, here you have $f_{X,Y} (x, y) =f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ so $X$ and $Y$ are independent (also identically distributed) and so $f_{X\mid Y} (x\mid y)=f_X(x)$

Comment: And I assume since $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_X(x)$, $P(X\gt 0|Y=0) = 1$?

Comment: Further comment: it doesn't seem that $\frac{4xy}{2y} = 2x$ is true as it is possible $y=0$.

Comment: Since $P(Y=0)=0$, conditioning on it can potentially lead to problems such as Borel–Kolmogorov paradoxes.  But if you say $f_{X\mid Y=y_0} (x\mid y) = \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}  f_{X\mid y_0 -\epsilon < Y < y_0 +\epsilon}(x\mid y) $ then you can find this when $y_0=0$ and you will get $2x$ as the conditional density